# Making RUNSQLSTM Display errors interactively

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

If I run the command `RUNSQLSTM SRCFILE(ZIPPY19811/QSQLSRC) SRCMBR(JUSTIN)` from the greenscreen,  I  get the status message `RUNSQLSTM command failed.` but to get the actual error message I have to do a WRKSPLF. Is there any way I could get the error message as a break message or in my job log? I'd just like the SQL parsing error, not all the extraneous (for debugging a simple syntax error) information in the job log.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of.

Why do you have syntax errors in the source member in the first place?

Use STRSQL or iNavigator's Run SQL Scripts to test an debug your statement.   Then store it in the sourc emember to be run with RUNSQLSTM.